# ReactiveCocoa chaining network operations failed

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, reactive-cocoa

I tried to use ReactiveCocoa to do network operation chaining, but I failed. I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

```
- (RACSignal *)pg_findObjectsInBackground {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

        [self findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                [subscriber sendError:error];
                return;
            }
            [subscriber sendNext:objects];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }];

        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            [self cancel];
        }];
    }];
}

- (RACSignal *)pg_countObjectsInBackground {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

        [self countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                [subscriber sendError:error];
                return;
            }
            [subscriber sendNext:@(number)];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }];

        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            [self cancel];
        }];
    }];
}
```

---

```
    __block NSError *_error;
    @weakify(self)
    [[[self.query pg_countObjectsInBackground]flattenMap:^RACStream *(NSNumber *count) {
        @strongify(self)
        self.totalCount = [count integerValue];
        // Second, fetch experiences
        self.query.limit = self.pageSize;
        self.query.skip = self.pageSize * self.currentPage;
        return [self.query pg_findObjectsInBackground];
    }]subscribeNext:^(NSArray *experiences) {
        @strongify(self)
        [self.experiences removeAllObjects];
        [self.experiences addObjectsFromArray:experiences];
    } error:^(NSError *error) {
        _error = error;
    } completed:^{
        @strongify(self)
        if (finishBlock) {
            finishBlock(self, _error);
        }
    }];
```

The first request was successful. But as soon as I return `[self.query pg_findObjectsInBackground]`, it went to `disposableWithBlock` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using the same `PFQuery` object for both the count and the find object operation, the query gets canceled when you return from the `flattenMap` method. The `flattenMap` subscribes to the new signal (which is the same signal), which I believe causes the disposable to fire. A simple solution is to construct a new `PFQuery` and return it in the `flattenMap` block.

I assumed you're using Parse, and if you are, you should tag it.